# Spring REST Request method 'DELETE', 'POST', 'PUT' not supported

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, postman

Creating very first SPRING REST API, for some reason only GET requests work as they should, all the rest - POST, PUT, DELETE do not.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/contacts")
public class ContactRESTController {

    private ContactService contactService;

    @Autowired
    public ContactRESTController(ContactService contactService) {
        this.contactService = contactService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/contact/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteContact(@PathVariable long id) {

        Contact retrived = contactService.findOne(id);
        if (retrived == null) { throw new ContactNotFoundException(id);}
        contactService.delete(id);
    }
```

Having @RestController allows me to omit @ResponseBody. Tried using @ResponseEntity with no effect. Thought it may be some security issues, so I've added this line into security.xml

```
<security:intercept-url method="DELETE" access="permitAll" pattern="/api/contacts/contact/*" />
```

when app loads I can see this line in console:

```
INFO - Mapped "{[/api/contacts/contact/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.bugielmarek.timetable.controllers.ContactRESTController.deleteContact(long)
```

yet when I pick DELETE in POSTMAN and go to

```
http://localhost:8080/crudone/api/contacts/contact/9
```

all I get is

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'DELETE' not supported
```

and down in Headers I can read 'allow - GET'.

Tried posting a DELETE request with 'Content-Type' set to 'text/html' with no luck.

UPDATE:

Adding hiddenHttpMethodFilter to web.xml was no help.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
       <servlet-name>crudone</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

UPDATE:

Following DwB suggestion I turned on DEBUG level and observed console output. What I found was:

```
DEBUG - /api/contacts/contact/10 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/crudone/api/contacts/contact/10
DEBUG - DispatcherServlet with name 'crudone' processing DELETE request for [/crudone/denied]
DEBUG - Looking up handler method for path /denied '
```

which suggests that it is problem with security after all.Any help how to disable csrf for REST would be much appreciated - as I suppose this is the solution.

Comment: Why is the `crudone` URL segment used in the example Postman URL? Is it defined in the source code?

Comment: What is your application ROOT?
change http://localhost:8080/crudone/api/contacts/contact/9
to http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/contact/9

Comment: @SergeyBrunov 'crudone' is a context root (if I got the lingo right). So that bit is not a problem I think.

Comment: @DwB marked my question as a duplicate indicating that it could already been answered - the solution would be to add a hiddenHttpMethodFilter, was happy to see it as my web.xml was lacking it indeed,unfortunately after adding it to web.xml same message appeared "WARN - Request method 'DELETE' not supported"

Comment: Turn on trace level debugging and troubleshoot the problem.  It does not appear to be related to anything you included in the question.

Comment: Problem solved. Many thanks.